# Cannot bind the property to the column

Tags: vb.net, datasource

I'm trying to display the serial number of the 'recipient' you selected in a textbox but I get this error:

```
System.ArgumentException: Cannot bind to the property or column RecipientSNo on the DataSource.
```

I did this to another textbox with a different query (same codes, just changed the column name from 'recipient' to 'issuer') just to debug and it works! I tried it again to the 'recipient' but it still doesn;t work.
My code:

```
    query("SELECT RecipientSNo FROM Recipient WHERE CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', MI, '. ', LastName) = '" & ReceiverName.Text & "';")
    Try
        adapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(CommandText, ServerString)
        table = New DataTable
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim bs As BindingSource
        adapter.Fill(ds, "recipient")
        bs = New BindingSource(ds, "recipient")
        DataBindings.Clear()
        ReceiverSNo.DataBindings.Add("text", bs, "ReceipientSNo")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
    disconnect()
```

---

This is the code from the 'issuer' which is working:

```
    query("SELECT IssuerSNo FROM Issuer WHERE CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', MI, '. ', LastName) = '" & IssuerName.Text & "';")
    Try
        adapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(CommandText, ServerString)
        table = New DataTable
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim bs As BindingSource
        adapter.Fill(ds, "armorer")
        bs = New BindingSource(ds, "armorer")
        IssuerSNo.DataBindings.Clear()
        IssuerSNo.DataBindings.Add("text", bs, "ArmorerSNo")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
    disconnect()
```

I just coped this code and changed the textbox and column names and it did not work already.. What seems to be the problem? I double checked my table and column names already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should write

```
ReceiverSNo.DataBindings.Clear()         
ReceiverSNo.DataBindings.Add("text", bs, "RecipientSNo")
```

The column returned from your query is called `RecipientSNo`,
the DataBindings.Add use `ReceipientSNo`